# My hangman game code in python is not giving correct output

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, loops, data-structures

I tried to create a hangman game in python but my output is weird. It's no giving output as I desired. Please help me.

```
guess_word = input("Enter the word to be guess")
guess_word_list = []
for i in range(0, len(guess_word)):
    guess_word_list.append("_")
guess_chances = 6
print("You can now guess letters")
while guess_chances > 0:
    guess_letter = input()
    for letter in guess_word:
        if letter == guess_letter:
            guess_word_list[guess_word.index(letter)] = guess_letter
            print(guess_word_list)
        else:
            guess_chances = guess_chances - 1
            print("Chances remaining {}".format(guess_chances))
count = 0
for letter in guess_word_list:
    if letter == "_":
        count += 1
if count == 0:
    print("Winner")
else:
    print("Looser")
```

Edit in from comment:

If the word to be guessed is `'mm.......'` so if I entered `'m'` then also only first "_" is replaced by `'m'`.

And if enter a wrong character then 2 chances are being reduced at one time.

Comment: What do you mean by 'weird output`? Please elaborate

Comment: what are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: if the word to be guessed is mm......so if I entered m then also only first  "_" is replaced by m. And if enter a wrong character then 2 chances are being reduced at one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that:

```py
guess_word = input("Enter the word to be guess: ")

guess_word_list = ['_']*len(guess_word)

guess_chances = 6

print("You can now guess letters")
while guess_chances > 0 and '_' in guess_word_list:
    guess_letter = input()
    correct_guess = False
    for i, letter in enumerate(guess_word):
        if letter == guess_letter:
            guess_word_list[i] = guess_letter
            correct_guess = True

    if not correct_guess:
        guess_chances = guess_chances - 1
        print("Chances remaining {}".format(guess_chances))
    else:
        print(''.join(guess_word_list))

if '_' not in guess_word_list:
    print('winner')
else:
    print('looser')
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

- When checking the letters, you're deducting chances with each non-matching letter. You should deduct a chance only if the letter is not found at all.
- In the main loop, check if the guess word is complete (no spaces left) so the loop exits

Try this code:

```
guess_word = input("Enter the word to be guess")
guess_word_list = []
for i in range(0, len(guess_word)):
    guess_word_list.append("_")
guess_chances = 6
print("You can now guess letters")
while guess_chances > 0 and '_' in guess_word_list:
    guess_letter = input()
    found = False
    for letter in guess_word:  # check all letters
        if letter == guess_letter:
            guess_word_list[guess_word.index(letter)] = guess_letter
            print(guess_word_list)
            found = True  # found letter in word
    if not found: # guess letter not in word
            guess_chances = guess_chances - 1
            print("Chances remaining {}".format(guess_chances))
count = 0
for letter in guess_word_list:
    if letter == "_":
        count += 1
if count == 0:
    print("Winner")
else:
    print("Looser")
```

One logic issue that still exists is the word must have unique letters. If the word is 'zoom', the game never ends because the loop always finds the first 'o'.

Comment: it's not working for word having the same letter twice or more.

Comment: I know. I mentioned that in the answer. You need to check if that spot is empty before updating the `guess_word_list` variable.